# How can I use a file from a remote repository into my Terraform file?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, terraform

I have this module to provision an EC2 instance using Terraform

```
module "EC2" {
  source          = "../Modules/ec2"
  ami             = "ami-xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  instance_type   = "t2.micro"
  userdata_1       = file("C:/Users/My_User/Documents/terraform/Modules/ec2/userdata_1.sh")

}
```

To test locally, I use File Function to call my userdata_1.sh from the directory where the EC2 resources are. I want now, push my terraform to GitHub, create a pipeline in Jenkins to use the terraform as CI/CD template and so on. It will fail once I test the pipeline in anywhere I would like to run the jenkins because it won't find my local directory. I tried to short the path to be something like `file("/terraform/Modules/ec2/userdata_1.sh")` but I got an error testing locally:

```
Invalid value for "path" parameter: no file exists at
terraform\Modules\ec2\userdata_1.sh; this function works only with files
that are distributed as part of the configuration source code, so if this file
will be created by a resource in this configuration you must instead obtain
this result from an attribute of that resource.
```

When I clone the repo I got the .sh script in the directory of the module.

Is there a way I can specify on that file path to use a path from a remote repository or use a default directory from a linux filesystem?

Comment: Have you tried `file("../Modules/ec2/userdata_1.sh")`? Why are you passing a file to a module, when the file already exists in that module? Inside the module if you just default `userdata_1` to be `file("${path.module}/userdata_1.sh")` it wouldn't need to be passed in.

Comment: Thanks you @MarkB. Without passing the file to the main and just using it in the module worked for me. So that way I can use it wherever it's cloned. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As outlined in the [terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/references.html):

> Filesystem and Workspace Info:

> `path.module` is the filesystem path of the module where the expression is placed.

> `path.root` is the filesystem path of the root module of the configuration.

> `path.cwd` is the filesystem path of the current working directory. In normal use of Terraform this is the same as path.root, but some advanced uses of Terraform run it from a directory other than the root module directory, causing these paths to be different.

Or in your case, as you need to give a relative path try something like this:

```
module "EC2" {
  source          = "../Modules/ec2"
  ami             = "ami-xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  instance_type   = "t2.micro"
  userdata_1       = file("${path.module}/Modules/ec2/userdata_1.sh")
}
```